# How to show whole content in Textview with scrolling left right not top bottm as show in screenshot?

Tags: android, textview

[image]

I have book content that will be shown in the textview with scrolling left right for next content. Is there any library or logic to show content like that?

Answer (score 0):

You should add some property into your textview XML tag such as

```
android:inputType="text"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

Use it, try and let me know if it works for you or not.
Happy to help you if you need to know more about it. 
Thanks.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I need to show the long text in Textview with swipeable page format like book and also change the text size by clicking button.